# Extract Text into Column using Regex

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, text-extraction, pypdf

I want to extract data (S no, Item Code, Price and Size) from the attached PDF Document in to columns.

The re.compile works for the S no, Item Code and Price, but as soon as I put the Size - it gives a limited output. I am unable to figure out why? Can you please help

(Attached picture of the PDF page)

[image]

```
Import pandas as pd
Import re
Import PyPDF2

file = open("Petchem.pdf", "rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)

my_dict = {"S no":[], "Item Code":[], "Price":[], "Size":[]}

for page in range (1,25):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)
    data = pageObj.extractText()

    size = re.compile(r'((\d{2,4}?)(\d{10})EA\s(\d?\d?,?\d?\d?\d.\d\d)[\s\w\d,:/.()-])')

    for number in size.findall(data):
        S_No = my_dict["S No"].append(number[1])
        Item_Code = my_dict["Item Code"].append(number[2])
        Price = my_dict["Price"].append(number[3])
        Size = my_dict["Size"].append(number[4]) 
        print(number[1])
        
a_file = open("Column_Breakup.csv", "w")
datadf = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
datadf.to_csv("Column_Breakup.csv")
a_file.close()
```

Comment: To be easier for people to help you should say what is going wrong when you run your code. As a tip I recommend you should print what your regex in finding before continuing to write the rest of code. Nevertheless, it seems that you have some syntax mistakes and other errors in there. I think your page iterartion shoudl be: `in range(1, 3):` and your should create list variables for your dictionary and append to them.

Comment: Thanks - I have corrected it. The regex compile lines works well for S No, Item Code and Price, when I add Size then the output get restricted. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.